# How to debug the server side of a nextjs app which is inside a docker container in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, next.js

I'm trying to debug the server side code of a nextjs app inside a docker container in VScode.
I added to the launch.json file this:

```
  {
    "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 3000,
    "address": "localhost",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "/app",
    "protocol": "inspector"
  }
```

but it doesn't work. I even exposed the port 9229 but it seems useless.
That's my folder structure:
[image]

Have you any suggestion?